# React Native OneSignal IOS alert issue

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, onesignal

I'm using onesignal-react-native for my react native app. However, I have an issue with alert on ios app. I don't know how to turn the alert off so that it doesn't show up when the users in app. How can I turn it off ?

Comment: Did you check the JSON response that one signal sends you?

Comment: @Raymond yes. but how can i turn it off ?. Seem like onesignal server didn's support the alert object. I can see the isInAppFocus object is true but can't do anything about it

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking into this in the future you will need to add this to your AppDelegate.m

```
self.oneSignal = [[RCTOneSignal alloc] initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                                                     appId:@"app-id"
                                                  settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : @(OSNotificationDisplayTypeNotification),kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : @YES}];
```

For android just add

```
OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);
```

Hope it helps.